# PHP session being duplicated in foreach loop

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to make sessions based off sql query data is being returned

this is my code:

```
$r = self::$db->fetch_row_assoc($sql);
$theme_dir = THEME_PATH . self::get_useragent() . "_UA_" . $flag . "_" . $r['theme_folder_name'];

if (self::$config['set_session'] == 1) {
    foreach ($r as $k => $v) {
        self::$session->set(self::get_useragent() . "_UA_" . $flag . "_" . $k, $v);
    }

    self::$session->set(self::get_useragent() . "_UA_" . $flag . "_theme_loaded",      1);
}
```

when this code is run the makes my sessions but i get something like

```
$_SESSION['Default_UA_landing_theme_id'] = 1
$_SESSION['Default_UA_landing_0'] = 1
```

it does this for every session that it creates, it makes 1 session with $k being the field name of the result returned by my query then it makes another with $k being the index of the $r array.

how can I just have it make one session per $k?

this is the method I use to query my datase

```
public function fetch_row_assoc($statement)
    {
        self::$PDO->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        try{
            $stmt = self::$PDO->query($statement); 
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH); //FETCH_BOTH
            return $result;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `FETCH_BOTH` (creates an array with both numeric *and* associative indexes) and then cycling through a `foreach`.  Why are you using `FETCH_BOTH` immediately after specifying `FETCH_ASSOC`?

Comment: well, i did make that method while researching how PDO handles queries. What would you suggest I fix it to?

Comment: its ok, i just set both to ASSOC and I got my results I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about what's going on in with `fetch_row_assoc`, I can't really be certain, but it looks like you've got numeric and non-numeric indexes in what should be an associative array. You should probably look at whatever class is behind `self::$db` and see if there isn't another method which could fix that.

If the library you're working with won't give you an associative array without numeric indexes, then you could solve the above issue with a test for `is_numeric`.

```
foreach ($r as $k => $v) {
    if( is_numeric( $k ) )
             self::$session->set(
                       self::get_useragent() . "_UA_" . $flag . "_" . $k, 
                       $v);
}
```

Comment: It seems the behavior of [`PDOStatemente::fetch()`](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), that fetches every column 2 times, both with the column order and the column name. @s2xi investigate inside `self::$db` and see if you can change that (or pass `$fetch_style = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as parameter. (edit: changed mysql to pdo)